# Can we track a remote reference without a pull / checkout / fetch with Git?

Tags: git, git-remote

I am creating a new git repository with

```
git init
```

I added the remote repository

```
git remote add origin https://<URL>.git
```

I want my local master to reference the HEAD of the origin/master.

I do not want to run pull / fetch / checkout  because of several reasons including the fact that it is very large and all I intend to do is to add files and not modify any existing file.

```
git remote show origin
```

shows the remote URLs for fetch and push and

```
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
```

I tried to

```
git branch --set-upstream-to master origin/master
```

but it results in

```
fatal: branch 'origin/master' does not exist
```

So is there no way I can make my local master HEAD ref remote master HEAD without causing the entire branch to be downloaded?

I tried fetching a single file from the origin/master but it errors out

```
git checkout origin/master -- README.md
```

gives the error

```
fatal: invalid reference: origin/master
```

and

```
git pull origin master -- README.md
```

results in

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref README.md

git branch -u origin/master
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist

git branch -u origin/master master
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist
```

Any way to get my local master ref the remote master HEAD and then I pull/checkout/fetch only those files that I need or only add files and push them?

Answer (score 1):

For you to use `--set-upstream-to`, the remote-tracking branch must exist.  Typically, the way that such a remote-tracking branch is created is by fetching the remote or pushing that branch to that remote.  It is possible to create the remote-tracking branch by hand with `git update-ref`, but that isn't likely to be useful here.  Git prevents you from specifying a nonexistent ref to prevent typing errors.

Be aware that if it's your intention to just add files to the remote and you do so without any of the history of the remote, your branches will form an independent root that will be hard to merge into the rest of the project.  People will generally not appreciate you creating such branches and they can behave oddly in some situations.

If your goal is to limit the amount of data you have to download, you may be better off doing a shallow fetch or shallow clone, which will download a limited history but still create relevant remote-tracking branches (allowing you to use `git branch --set-upstream-to`) and work with the remote project in the customary way.  You could do this with `git pull --depth=1 origin master`, for example.

Comment: git pull --depth=1 origin master does no solve my problem because the last commit from the head is the large commit. So even with --depth=1 I see the whole repository.

Comment: However going on this line of thought, can I fetch a much earlier version (such as the first committed version) which only had 1 README.md file and then add the newer files and the push the changes? Sounds wrong but just a thought.

The only other option I can think of is to branch at the earlier version on the remote and then ref it and then commit but then how do I merge it back into the master without requiring to pull everything.

Comment: If the problem is the size of the checkout, you can also use sparse checkout to check out only the files you need.  However, if you're working with a repo and need to interact with others, you need to have at least one commit in the branch you want to base your code off of, so you'll need to have at least that much in the history of your master branch.  Picking an ancient version to base off of is likely going to lead to conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by bk2204 above some RnD on my part I found at least 2 very powerful techniques to achieve the above stated goal, which was to reduce the size of the repository fetched when cloning from remote as we may not want to work on most of the files some of which may be very large.

In my specific case I had a 140 MB repository. This is not very large but 139MB of this was a one time commit for the existing web server files including jars and jpgs. None of these were intended to be edited for a long time.

I wanted to clone the repository to modify 1 text file and add a few files. However in all cases that I tried I had to download the complete 140 MB. Ironically in my attempts to avoid downloading 140 MB, I landed up downloading the folder 12 odd times!

Finally there seem to be 2 solutions, I am adding the links below

1. [Git Partial cloning](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone)
2. [Git Sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)

Sparse checkout superbly explained in the context of the Mono project at

[Bring your monorepo down to size with sparse-checkout](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/)